# Split the string with different length

Tags: java, java-8

I have a String `String s = " ABCD 1122-12-12"`, i.e `<space or single digit number>+<any string>+<space>+<date in YYYY-mm-dd>` format.

What could be the regex for String.split method or any other utility methods to split the above string into three parts

`[0] = <space or single digit number> = " "`

`[1] = <string> = "ABCD"`

`[2] = <date in YYYY-mm-dd> = "1122-12-12"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Regex would be nuking the mosquito.  Just use the `charAt`, `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods.

Comment: Would not (\s|\d)(.+)\s+(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) do? https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

The regex `( |\d)(.+) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` should do the job.

```java
String input = " ABCD 1122-12-12";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("( |\\d)(.+) (\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
  String spaceOrDigit = matcher.group(1);
  String string = matcher.group(2);
  String date = matcher.group(3);
  System.out.println("spaceOrDigit = '" + spaceOrDigit + "'");
  System.out.println("string = '" + string + "'");
  System.out.println("date = '" + date + "'");
}
```

Output:

```
spaceOrDigit = ' '
string = 'ABCD'
date = '1122-12-12'
```